# Slack plugin installation for Pentaho Kettle is failing - MacOS

Tags: pentaho, kettle, slack

I'm running kettle from mac os and I try to install the slack plugin using kettle's UI (in the Marketplace window).

The installation is failing and from the logs I have the following message :

```
16:31:14,723 ERROR [DiPluginService] ERROR on delete or create org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
Unable get file from https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/pdi-graphiq-marketplace/SlackBotJobEntry.zip
```

I was hopping to install this plugin manually from this git repo : https://github.com/tsykes/pdi-slackbot-plugin but I don't understand if need to build the project ? Plus it looks like I need to use Apach ant, which I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using now an older version of Pentaho Kettle (6.1) where the slack plugin works